# positioning semantic-ui icon

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am currently working on a project and I need some help trying to position an icon on the upper right corner of the page. Ive ben playing around with it but haven't had any luck. I am using the semantic-ui icon

```
import React from 'react'
import { Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const ShoppingCart = () => {

  return(

    <Icon.Group size='big'>
      <Icon link name='shopping cart' />
      <Icon corner='top right'/>
    </Icon.Group>
  )
}

export default ShoppingCart;
```

this is the css that I am using for the positioning

```
i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3000px;
  /* left: 80%; */
  margin-left: 380px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi hannah, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a cutom class name to your `icon`,

```
<Icon.Group size="big" className="shopping_cart_icon">
   <Icon link name="shopping cart" />
   <Icon corner="top right" />
</Icon.Group>
```

Using this class name you can apply the `CSS`, `top: 0` & `right:0` will place your icon to *upper right corner*.

```
.shopping_cart_icon{
   position : absolute;
   top : 0;
   right : 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-ifkyc?fontsize=14)

Comment: do you happen to know how I can adjust the position... like if I want to movie it down a little bit or to the left a little bit?

Comment: never mind I got it, I tried using the percentages and I can adjust it

Comment: @hannah, keep percentages as last option, try to manage using `px/rem` like, `.shopping_cart_icon{
   position : absolute;
   top : 50px;
   right : 50px;
}`